# When you install TFS on the application tier, does that affect the databases on the data tier?

Tags: sql, tfs

I only installed TFS 2013 on the application tier and didn't go through the configuration wizard to upgrade to 2013.2. Do I need to restore any databases if I restore a snapshot of the application tier? (Does just installing new bits of TFS on the app tier affect the data tier?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No installing the bits does not affect the data tier. You need to configure the application tier to point at the data tier before it will have any effect.

If you already have databases and you are upgrading in place then you can just "configure app tier only".

If you are on new hardware then you need to follow the new hardware workflow to install...

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404869.aspx